# Flutter align text in multiple rows

Tags: flutter, text-alignment, flutter-row

I have this card:
[image: What i have]

This is the code of one row (I have 6 rows):

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    ClipOval(
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 20,
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
    ),
    Text('Example 1'),
    Text('96\'')
  ],
),
SizedBox(height: 8),
...
```

These rows are inside a Column that is inside a Container (All wrapped in a Card)
What should I change to get the result shown in the photo

What i want:
[image: What i want]
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) and [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) to achieve such behavior.
Just change your `Row` to the following

```
Row(
      children: [
        ClipOval(
          child: Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(text1),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(text2),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

[image]